# Laravel Email Attach From Storage File Not Found Exception

Tags: laravel

recently i'm trying to send email with attachment from the local storage.
The file is put under the `storage/app/reservation/this-is.pdf`

here is my mailable

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('email.reservation_info')
        ->subject('Your Hotel Reservation')
        ->attachFromStorage($this->pdfPath,$this->pdfName,[
            'mime' => 'application/pdf'
        ])
        ->with([
            'result' => $this->result
        ]);
}
```

as the code above, i put the pdf path and also the pdf name. but i got an error like this

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException    
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kema/storage/app/reservation/DEV2008070001.pdf
```

i also try to check if the file exist, but as i check the file is already exist.

can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have wrong arguments in `attachFromStorage`
From laravel's source code

```
 /**
 * Attach a file to the message from storage.
 *
 * @param  string  $disk
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string|null  $name
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return $this
 */
public function attachFromStorageDisk($disk, $path, $name = null, array $options = [])
{
    $this->diskAttachments = collect($this->diskAttachments)->push([
        'disk' => $disk,
        'path' => $path,
        'name' => $name ?? basename($path),
        'options' => $options,
    ])->unique(function ($file) {
        return $file['name'].$file['disk'].$file['path'];
    })->all();

    return $this;
}
```

This should fix your code

```
return $this->markdown('email.reservation_info')
    ->subject('Your Hotel Reservation')
    ->attachFromStorageDisk('local', $this->pdfPath,$this->pdfName,[
        'mime' => 'application/pdf'
    ])
    ->with([
        'result' => $this->result
    ]);
```

`$this->pdfPath` should be relative path to the pdf file, not the absolute one. If you have full path then use `attach` method (full signature `public function attach($file, array $options = [])`)

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment. i got this error

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailable::attachFromStorage() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kema/app/Mail/SendInfoReservation.php on line 37

Comment: What version of laravel you are running?

Comment: currently using 6.0

Comment: i made a mistake, use ```attachFromStorageDisk```

Comment: still get error file not found..
eventhough i use absolute or relative file path still not found.

$pdfPath = storage_path('app/reservation/'.$pdfName);

or 

$pdfPath = storage_path('app/reservation');

Comment: What is the path inside localstorage that you are sending to the server

Comment: also here if i return the path /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kema/storage/app/reservation/DEV2008070001.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219508/discussion-between-dusan-malusev-and-abdan-syakuro).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  You are using `attachFromStorage` which as pointed out by Dusan Malusav needs a relative path.  [All your arguments are correct](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/0fa361d0e2e111a1a684606a675b414ebd471257) for the `attachFromStorage` method.  So you either have to only use:
`app/reservation/DEV2008070001.pdf` as relative path since the `attachFromStorage` will fill in the rest,

Or use absolute path:

```
->attach('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kema/storage/app/reservation/DEV2008070001.pdf', [ //absolute path
       'as' => 'DEV2008070001.pdf',
       'mime' => 'application/pdf'
 ]);
```